# Is there any method to programmatically switch focus out of metro mode?

Tags: winapi, windows-8, microsoft-metro

If I have a program running in the background and it needs the user to see it (like a dialog box) when it pops up, can I take the user out of Metro Mode (in Windows 8) for him to be able to see this notification?

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt it, such a capability would spawn a bunch of apps that would essentially try to take over and be very jarring for the user.  Your desktop app though could generate a toast notification that would alert the user there is some action to take, see [this MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh779727.aspx#sending_toast_notifications_from_desktop_apps) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jim: switching context automatically from the desktop to Metro (or whatever they're calling it now) would be visually jarring and user-hostile. I realize the OS itself does this, like when you launch a desktop app from the Start screen. That doesn't make it good design.

Besides, when it does it, the user (presumably) wanted to interact with the newly-launched application. That's not necessarily the case when you're just showing a notification. There may not even be action required.

Instead, I recommend that you use [Toast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779727), the notification framework designed explicitly for this purpose. There's a sample application available for download: [Sending toast notifications from desktop apps](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Sending-toast-notifications-71e230a2).

Note, however, that in order for Toast notifications to work from desktop applications, you must install a shortcut to your desktop application in the Start screen, with a [`System.AppUserModel.ID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dd391569.aspx). This should be handled by your installer. More information is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802762.aspx).

Of course, the user can disable this by either turning off notifications or removing your app's shortcut from their Start screen. That's perfectly okay—if they take either of these actions, you can assume that they no longer want to receive notifications from your app.

Comment: Nuts. I only read the first sentence of Jim's answer before posting this. I see he's made exactly the same recommendation. Oh well, I'll leave this for the additional links.

Comment: LOL, you were a lot more descriptive (read: less lazy :)) than I!